# Forcing enumerated \bibitems using bib units

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, bibunits

I'm editing my CV and I wanted to use the `bibunits` package to make separate mini-bibliographies for different sections.  Here is some code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ManyBibs]{currvita}
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\defaultbibliography{test}
\defaultbibliographystyle{acm}

\newenvironment{cvseclist}[1]
{\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\sc #1}%
\begin{cvlist}{\sc #1}}
{\end{cvlist}}

\newcommand\multilinelabel[1]{%
\smash{\parbox[t]{\cvlabelwidth}{\raggedright #1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pubs[2]{%
\item[\sc \multilinelabel{#1}]
\begin{bibunit}%
    \nocite{#2}%
    \putbib
\end{bibunit}%
\IfFileExists{\@bibunitname.bbl}{}{Run \texttt{bibtex
\@bibunitname}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{Anand D. Sarwate \hfill Curriculum Vit\ae}


\begin{cvseclist}{Publications}
\pubs{Journal Papers}{test1,test2,test3}
\end{cvseclist}

\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

I couldn't figure out how to use `filecontents` so it is faster to provide `test.bib` here:

```
@article{test3,
Author = {A. D. Sarwate},
Journal = {Baz : Theory and Applications},
Number = {1},
Title = {Baz is meh},
Volume = {1},
Year = {2011}}

@article{test2,
Author = {A. D. Sarwate},
Journal = {IEEE Transactions on Bar},
Number = {2},
Title = {Bar is better},
Volume = {8},
Year = {2010}}

@article{test1,
Author = {A. D. Sarwate},
Journal = {Journal of Foo Studies},
Number = {3},
Title = {Foo is awesome},
Volume = {12},
Year = {2009}}
```

But when I put in `\pubs{Journal Papers}{test1,test2,test3}`, I get an unnumbered list of `bibitems`.  What I want is a numbered bibliography, so that it looks something like:

**Journal Papers**

[1] A.D. Sarwate, "Foo is awesome", *Journal of Foo Studies* 12(3), 2009.

[2] A.D. Sarwate, "Bar is better", *IEEE Transactions on Bar* 8(2), 2010.

[3] A.D. Sarwate, "Baz is meh", *Baz : Theory and Applications*, Los Angeles, CA, June 2011.

and each `bibunit` is independently numbered.  The lack of numbering I see now seems to not change with the bibliography style I use.  Is there a way to force BibTeX to number each `bibunit`?

Is this a problem with `\nocite`?  If I change the command to use `\cite` then the `\cite` command produces numbers like `[1-3]` but the bibliography remains unnumbered.

Comment: Please change your given code to an complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and include the `bib` file with the package `filecontents` in your MWE. I tried your snippet and had no problems ...

Comment: I tried the snippet as well, an it works.

Comment: I am not sure how to use filecontents but I will edit the above with a minimal (to me) example -- the problem may be with the interaction of commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on `etoolbox` is the following

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{mybibitem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{bibunit}{\setcounter{mybibitem}{0}}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\apptocmd{\@bibitem}{\stepcounter{mybibitem}[\themybibitem] }{}{}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sorry to delay, but this worked like a charm!

Comment: @AnandSarwate glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Save this as `currvita1.sty` and put it in the same directory as your `cv.tex` (say) file.

```
%%
%% This is file `currvita1.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% currvita.dtx  (with options: `package')
%%
%% LaTeX package for a curriculum vitae
%%
%% Copyright (C) 1999 Axel Reichert
%% See the files README and COPYING.
%%
%% \CharacterTable
%%   {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]%
\ProvidesPackage{currvita1}[%
  1999/09/13 v0.9i Typesetting a Curriculum Vitae%
]%
\RequirePackage{ifthen}%
\newcommand*{\@cvplace}{\@empty}%
\newsavebox{\@cvlistheading}%
\newlength{\cvlabelsep}%
\newlength{\cvlabelskip}%
\newlength{\cvlabelwidth}%
\newboolean{cv@many@bibs}%
\newboolean{cv@no@date}%
\newboolean{cv@open@bib}%
\DeclareOption{LabelsAligned}{%
  \setlength{\cvlabelskip}{0ex}%
}%
\DeclareOption{TextAligned}{%
  \setlength{\cvlabelskip}{%
    1.5\baselineskip plus 3pt minus 3pt%
  }%
}%
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
  \@ifundefined{bibindent}{%
    \newlength{\bibindent}%
  }{}%
  \setlength{\bibindent}{1.5em}%
  \setboolean{cv@open@bib}{true}%
}%
\DeclareOption{ManyBibs}{%
  \setboolean{cv@many@bibs}{true}%
}%
\DeclareOption{NoDate}{%
  \setboolean{cv@no@date}{true}%
}%
\ExecuteOptions{TextAligned}%
\ProcessOptions*%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\cvlabelsep}{1em}%
  \settowidth{\cvlabelwidth}{%
    \cvlabelfont 88/8888--88/8888%
  }%
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cvheadingfont}{\bfseries\Large}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cvbibname}{Publications}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cvplace}[1]{%
  \gdef\@cvplace{#1}%
}%
\providecommand*{\date}[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}%
\newenvironment{cv}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\@empty}}{%
  }{%
    {%
      \noindent\cvheadingfont#1\par\nopagebreak
    }%
  }%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@many@bibs}}{%
    \DeclareRobustCommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{[##1]}%
  }{}%
  \providecommand{\newblock}{%
    \hspace{0.11em plus 0.33em minus 0.07em}%
  }%
  \long\def\thebibliography##1{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@many@bibs}}{%
    }{%
      {%
        \noindent\cvlistheadingfont\cvbibname
        \par\nopagebreak
      }%
    }%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@open@bib}}{%
      \renewcommand{\newblock}{\par}%
    }{}%
    \begin{list}{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}{%
      \setlength{\parsep}{0ex}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{%
        0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt%
      }%
      \setlength{\topsep}{0ex}%
      \setlength{\partopsep}{0ex}%
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@many@bibs}}{%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{.8em}%
      }{}%
      \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\@biblabel{##1}}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@open@bib}}{%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibindent}%
        \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibindent}%
        \setlength{\listparindent}{\itemindent}%
      }{}%
      \usecounter{enumiv}%
      \let\p@enumiv\@empty
      \renewcommand*{\theenumiv}{\@arabic\c@enumiv}%
    }%
    \sloppy
    \clubpenalty4000%
    \@clubpenalty\clubpenalty
    \widowpenalty4000%
    \sfcode`\.=\@m
  }%
  \long\def\endthebibliography{%
    \renewcommand*{\@noitemerr}{%
      \@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}%
    }%
    \end{list}%
  }%
}{%
  \vspace{1.333\baselineskip plus 3pt minus 3pt}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@cvplace}{\@empty}}{%
  }{%
    \noindent
    \@cvplace
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@no@date}}{}{%
      ,~%
    }%
  }%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{cv@no@date}}{}{%
    \@date
  }%
  \par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cvlistheadingfont}{%
  \bfseries\large
}%
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\cvlabelfont}{%
  \normalsize
}%
\newenvironment{cvlist}[1]{%
  \sbox{\@cvlistheading}{\cvlistheadingfont#1}%
  \begin{list}{}{%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{%
        \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\usebox{\@cvlistheading}}%
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\@tempdima > 0pt}}{%
          \settowidth{\@tempdimb}{\cvlabelfont##1}%
          \ifthenelse{%
            \lengthtest{\@tempdima < \cvlabelwidth} \and
            \lengthtest{\@tempdimb = 0pt}}{%
            \parbox[b]{\cvlabelwidth}{%
              \vspace{\cvlabelskip}%
              \makebox[\cvlabelwidth][l]{%
                \box\@cvlistheading
              }%
            }%
          }{%
            \parbox[b]{0pt}{%
              \makebox[0pt][l]{\box\@cvlistheading}%
              \\*[0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt]%
            }%
          }%
        }{}%
        \cvlabelfont##1\hfill
      }%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0ex}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{%
        0.5\baselineskip plus 1pt minus 1pt%
      }%
      \setlength{\topsep}{%
        1\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 2pt%
      }%
      \setlength{\partopsep}{0ex}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\cvlabelsep}%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\cvlabelwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\cvlabelwidth}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\cvlabelsep}%
    }%
}{%
  \end{list}%
}%
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `currvita1.sty'.
```

And your `cv.tex` file becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[ManyBibs]{currvita1} %% note the change from currvita
\usepackage{bibunits}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},breaklinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
 @article{test3,
Author = {A. D. Sarwate},
Journal = {Baz : Theory and Applications},
Number = {1},
Title = {Baz is meh},
Volume = {1},
Year = {2011}}

@article{test2,
Author = {A. D. Sarwate},
Journal = {IEEE Transactions on Bar},
Number = {2},
Title = {Bar is better},
Volume = {8},
Year = {2010}}

@article{test1,
Author = {A. D. Sarwate},
Journal = {Journal of Foo Studies},
Number = {3},
Title = {Foo is awesome},
Volume = {12},
Year = {2009}}
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter

\makeatother
\defaultbibliography{test}
\defaultbibliographystyle{acm}

\newenvironment{cvseclist}[1]
{\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\sc #1}%
\begin{cvlist}{\sc #1}}
{\end{cvlist}}

\newcommand\multilinelabel[1]{%
\smash{\parbox[t]{\cvlabelwidth}{\raggedright #1}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pubs[2]{%
\item[\sc \multilinelabel{#1}]
\begin{bibunit}%%[plain]%
    \nocite{#2}%
    \putbib%%[test]
\end{bibunit}%
\IfFileExists{\@bibunitname.bbl}{}{\immediate\write18 {bibtex    %%% changed here
\@bibunitname}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{cv}{Anand D. Sarwate \hfill Curriculum Vit\ae}
\begin{cvseclist}{Publications}
\pubs{Journal Papers}{test1,test2}
\pubs{Conference Papers}{test3}
\end{cvseclist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image]